# Getting error when high charts library included in java project, maven throwing errors

Tags: highcharts

After including the high charts custom js in library or  full highchart js code and ran maven, but it's throwing the following errors:

> [ERROR] highcharts-custom.src.js [63202:44]: missing name after .
>   operator [ERROR]highcharts-custom.src.js:line 63202:column 44:missing
>   name after . operator [ERROR]highcharts-custom.src.js [67212:27]:
>   syntax error [ERROR]highcharts-custom.src.js:line 67212:column
>   27:syntax error [ERROR]highcharts-custom.src.js:line 67213:column
>   35:syntax error [ERROR]highcharts-custom.src.js:line 67214:column
>   22:syntax error

I tried with both Highcharts custom build js and full highchart js code in to the project and getting above Maven build errros from both highchart versions downloaded from high chart website. I am  using follwing libaries, Highchart-7.1.2 , jquery-3.3.1, Apache Maven 3.5.2, apache-tomcat-8.5.39, jdk1.8.0_212, jre1.8.0_212,  any one please help me out. I tried to include both Highcharts custom build js and full code both getting same above errors.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Poor, unchecked grammar and formatting makes this question very hard to understand. Furthermore, how did you manage to get into the error message?

Comment: Hi @Roop, Could you describe your problem more precisely and add a list of what libraries and tools do you use?

Comment: @ppotaczek, I was trying to include Highcharts custom js in to the project and getting above Maven build errros from Highcharts custom js file downloaded from high chart website.   I am  using follwing libaries

Comment: @ppotaczek, I was trying to include Highcharts custom js in to the project and getting above Maven build errros from Highcharts custom js file downloaded from high chart website.   I am  using follwing libaries, 1. jquery-3.3.1
2. Apache Maven 3.5.2
3. apache-tomcat-8.5.39
4. jdk1.8.0_212
5. jre1.8.0_212,  any one please help me out.

Comment: stackNew - Did you try to use the original, unchanged Highcharts source code? If so, has it worked?

Comment: @ppotaczek, I tried both custom and full code bundle for both I am getting same errors

Comment: stackNew - Are you sure you are fulfilling the [Highcharts system requirements](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/system-requirements)? Maybe you need to use some Java [wrapper](https://www.highcharts.com/products/wrappers)? For example: https://www.hyjavacharts.com/

Comment: @ppotaczek thanks for your suggestion, I found the issue, my project has extra maven plugin called YUI Compressor, it is trying to compress them and causing issue. by adding code to excluded the higchart files in pom.xml solved the issues.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my own issue, my project has extra maven plugin called YUI Compressor, it is trying to compress them and causing issue. by adding code to excluded the higchart files in pom.xml and directly added minified files in to project solved the issues.